# How to find Euler Angle Parametrization of a given SU(4) matrix

Tags: group-theory

The Euler angle parametrization of an $SU(4)$ matrix is given by:

[image]

Where the $\lambda_i$'s are the generators of $SU(4)$.

If I have a valid $SU(4)$ matrix given below:
[image]

How do I find angles $\alpha_i$ that generate this matrix?

Comment: Any reason why?

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with a function that will work beautifully with this parametrization rather than the overall matrix.